# Error while running execFileSync in packaged Electron app

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I ran the following code in packaged electron app by electron-packager(asar=false).

```
const app = require(‘electron’);
const { join } = require(‘path’);
const EXEC_OPTS = {encoding: 'utf-8', shell: true};
childProcess.execFileSync(join(app.getAppPath(), 'src', 'executable') + ‘/test.sh’, [''], EXEC_OPTS);
```

But I got nothing even error logs..

This code normally can run only by command of “electron .”  ,
But this code cannot run after packaging by electron packager .

Structure is like this (just wrote necessary part. )

project/src/excutable/test.sh

project/main.js

Any idea?

Comment: What errors exactly are produced when you run this code?

Comment: I did not get any errors.
It ran but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the path could be wrong after packaging. You should try to do a `console.log(app.getAppPath());` (e.g. send to renderer, write to a log file etc.) in your app to double check if it is pointing to the expected path.

Comment: I do not have a way to look the main process log after packaging..
I could look only render process log...
but I think electron shows an error dialog if the path is wrong.

Comment: If the cause is the launch of the .sh script it may not print an error message. I would recommend you to check the path. Also I would check dynamic path variables in your sh script.

Comment: thank you, I will try it.
Is there any way to get logs for the main process after packaging?

Comment: Something like this should work: "var fs = require('fs'); fs.writeFileSync('mylog.txt', app.getAppPath());

Comment: I tried "fs.writeFileSync", and I get expected path which is "/Users/username/project/bin/project-darwin-x64/project.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/executable/test.sh". 
Also, I confirmed execFileSync result buffer by the above way, but the result was empty...
What does this mean...? .sh is not executed? 
Anyway, I will try to check the dynamic path in the shell script next.

Comment: app.getAppPath() 
was  "/Users/username/project/bin/project-darwin-x64/project.app"

Comment: I checked the dynamic path in the shell script ("pwd" in shell script), 
and the path was "/" which means root directory(pc’s).
Then write command failed.
so I add “cd `dirname $0` on top of .sh, and the .sh work well.
Thank you very much, @11AND2.

Comment: Great :-). Could you mark it as answered so others know they should first check their path variables in these kind of situations?