# Electron-builder - path to include sqlite database in dev && production

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm using this template

https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue

and including a sqlite file in static/db/database.sqlite

in my main.js I have this

```
const SQL = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var path = require('path');
const db = new SQL.Database(path.join(__static, '/db/database.sqlite'));
```

it works fine for dev, but when building for production, I receive this message in devtools:

SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like another case of messed up path variables after packaging. I would recommend to debug your paths, for instance with fs:

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
fs.writeFileSync('mylog.txt', __dirname);
```

Reference: [Error while running execFileSync in packaged Electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50693947/error-while-running-execfilesync-in-packaged-electron-app/50695228#50695228)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, forgot to update this here:

https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/630

Basically, it's supposed to user the userData folder in order to use read/write operations.. so... _static is not intended to be a folder to write content to.